# I am trying to subtract but it is always adding one variable with another

Tags: javascript, function

globally defined variables

```
let firstNumber = 0;
let secondNumber = 0;
let clearValue;
let operator = "";
const divs = document.querySelectorAll("#panel div");
```

div selection and variable assignment

```
divs.forEach((div) => {
  div.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let selection1 = div.id;
    switch (selection1) {
      case "one":
        inputArea.value += "1";
        break;
      case "two":
        inputArea.value += "2";
        break;
      case "three":
        inputArea.value += "3";
        break;
      case "four":
        inputArea.value += "4";
        break;
      case "five":
        inputArea.value += "5";
        break;
      case "six":
        inputArea.value += "6";
        break;
      case "seven":
        inputArea.value += "7";
        break;
      case "eight":
        inputArea.value += "8";
        break;
      case "nine":
        inputArea.value += "9";
        break;
      case "zero":
        inputArea.value += "0";
        break;
      case "decimal":
        inputArea.value += ".";
        break;
      case "clear":
        clearValue = inputArea.value;
        clearValue = firstNumber.slice(0, -1);
        inputArea.value = clearValue;
        break;
      case "allClear":
        inputArea.value = "";
        break;
      case "add":
        operator = "+";
        firstNumber = parseFloat(inputArea.value);
        inputArea.value = "+";
        break;
      case "subtract":
        operator = "-";
        firstNumber = parseFloat(inputArea.value);
        inputArea.value = "-";
        break;
      case "divide":
        operator = "/";
        firstNumber = parseFloat(inputArea.value);
        inputArea.value = "/";
        break;
      case "multiply":
        operator = "x";
        firstNumber = parseFloat(inputArea.value);
        inputArea.value = "x";
        break;
      case "module":
        operator = "%";
        firstNumber = parseFloat(inputArea.value);
        inputArea.value = "%";
        break;
      case "equal":
        secondNumber = parseFloat(inputArea.value);
        console.log(secondNumber);
        inputArea.value = calculate(firstNumber, operator, secondNumber);
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

calculate function

```
 const calculate = (num1, oper, num2) => {
      num1 = parseFloat(num1);
      num2 = parseFloat(num2);
      switch (oper) {
        case "+":
          console.log(num1 + num2);
          return num1 + num2;
        case "-":
          console.log(num1 - num2);
          return num1 - num2;
        case "x":
          return num1 * num2;
        case "/":
          return num1 / num2;
        case "%":
          return num1 % num2;
      }
    };
```

This is the link to my full code.**https://codepen.io/reddevil-1/pen/mdWqYbN**.

I am trying to make a calculator, for that I have provided an input field where user can click a button on the calculator in order to give some value as input. when I enter my first value and then press on an operator button, i save the input field value into a variable called as 'first number', then i store the operator in a variable called operator, and on click of '=', I store the other number in a variable called the secondNumber, and then i call a function for calculation part. Using the switch case, I am checking the value of the operator and then returning the value accordingly. The addition works fine, but when I try to subtract a number, it still ends up adding them. Can anyone tell me, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you are getting the operator sign in your `secondNumber` as well.

```
 case "equal":
        secondNumber = parseFloat(inputArea.value);
        console.log(secondNumber);
        inputArea.value = calculate(firstNumber, operator, secondNumber);
        break;
```

Here your `inputArea` also has the operator to use so when you do `2 - 2` your `firstNumber` is `2` operator is `-` and your second number is `-2`.

so `( 2 - (-2) ) = 4`

And that's the reason your other operators are also not working

if lets say you want to multiply by `2` your `secondNumber` will be
`parseFloat('x2') = NaN`

Try removing all extra signs except numbers and dots like below for calculating `secondNumber`

```
 case "equal":
        secondNumber = parseFloat(inputArea.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""));
        console.log(secondNumber);
        inputArea.value = calculate(firstNumber, operator, secondNumber);
        break;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that in your `numericals`(0-9) press case, you are appending the string with pressed number, but the string already contains operator value ( eg. +, -, etc etc )

So , lets try to understand what is happening in subtract flow -

1. User presses `5`:

   inputArea.value = '5'
2. User presses `-`:

   inputArea.value = '-'

   operator = '-'
3. User press `4`:

   inputArea.value = '-4' (Since you are appening)

   operator = '-'

Then your call your `calculate` function with values - `(5, '-', '-4')` which results into `5 - (-4)` => `5 + 4`, hence it is adding even when you are subtracting.

Answer (score 1):

You solution is a bit complicated. What about this. There is just one event listner for all the buttons. The calculation is done with `Function('return' + exp)()` as alternative to ´eval()´ or the complicated switch that you have.

```js
var arr = [];

const calculate = expression => {
  return Function('return ' + expression)();
};

const update = str => {
  document.getElementById('line').innerText = str;
};

document.getElementById('buttons').addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.nodeName == 'BUTTON') {
    let value = e.target.attributes['data-value'].value;
    if (value == '=') {
      update(calculate(arr.join('')));
      arr = [];
    } else {
      arr.push(value);
      update(arr.join(''));
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#line {
  font-family: mono;
  border: thin solid black;
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
  <button data-value="1">1</button>
  <button data-value="2">2</button>
  <button data-value="3">3</button>
  <button data-value="+">+</button>
  <button data-value="-">-</button>
  <button data-value="=">=</button>
</div>
<div id="line"></div>
```

Comment: This code surely helps in shortening my code, but since I am new to the programming world, this is a bit confusing. Thanks for your help though.